# Running binaries on Fedora 17 that were built in Fedora 13

Tags: linux, installation, compatibility, fedora

Is it safe to run binaries on Fedora 17 that were built in Fedora 13?  It's C++ code, compiled with g++, and we're using stl containers, posix socket library, and others.

Would it be possible to build the binaries on a Fedora 13 machine so they would work with a Fedora 17 machine?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, if your binaries actually run, the results will be correct. Most libraries these days have "version checking". Of course the "and others" may be cause for concern if they are minor libraries that aren't compatible.

The "safe" way to avoid this sort of problem is to either:
 1. Compile the binaries as static - meaning that the binary doesn't rely on shared libraries -> no problem with compatibility (the Linux kernel itself is generally safe over many generations - I have regularly changed from a 2.6 to a 3.8 kernel with no issues at work - at home I run Fedora 16 and 17 on my two machines, and binaries DO work between these). 
 2. Recompile on the new target system.

Answer (score 2):

The "and others" matters. Fedora does not tend to keep old library versions around, so you may need to package or supply older versions of the libraries used if these are not available on Fedora 17.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will need to do more research as to which libraries are used and which ones could potentially cause compatibility issues. Would I only have to worry about dynamically linked libraries and not statically linked libraries?  Also, would the kernel being a different version be an issue or should I only be worried about libraries?

Comment: Only dynamically-linked libraries matter, but you may have trouble finding static libraries to link against in Fedora since it's against the packaging rules to include them in the main library packages. The kernel version generally doesn't matter as long as you aren't using some exotic mechanism which would be removed in the newer kernel.